# my app crashes when opening on an android device 'app keeps stopping' error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app keeps crashing when opening see screenshot
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JytST.png)

Have the following error as the app keeps crashing and will not open.see screenshot:

```
 2020-06-27 16:41:02.877 5788-5788/com.appload.kenny E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.appload.kenny, PID: 5788
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libplayer.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.appload.kenny.PTPlayer.<clinit>(PTPlayer.java:115)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at         androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when a native library module `*.so` is not found for the targeted SoC architecture. For example if native library is only available for 32 bit SoC then it might have a problem in 64 bit SoC and vice versa.

Try checking if any `ndk` filter is applied. e.g. :

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
```

Alternatively you can add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to use deprecated ndk.

To know more on SoC architecture, go here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

Comment: Glad I could help :)